# FXML get controller and stylesheet

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-2, fxml

Given a FXML file, is there a way to get the class controller name and the stylesheet name without using javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader() or parsing the XML file myself?

Comment: you are sort-of asking if there's a way to retrieve this info without using any of the tools designed to retrieve this info.

Comment: No... I'm loading a FXML at runtime but I can't call FXMLLoader() because the FXML has a fx:controller which is not a class in my package. So, first I have to read the controller class name, load that class from the jar and then I can use FXMLLoader(). I thought that maybe there was a way to load a FXML and get a list of its properties without me parsing it.

Comment: hmm... not sure actually then. i've done javafx work (love it!), but haven't had this need come up. Perhaps reading the file itno memory as a string, then doing an indexOf("fx:controller") and returning the substring might get what you want. depending on your FXML size, it could be a lot of memory usage though...